# Mac set up 'wizard'

Tags: macos, mac, setup

When starting up a Mac for the first time, it runs a 'wizard' that asks various questions (what language, what iTunes account etc.)
As far as I can tell, this only runs the first time the Mac is run ....

Is it possible to run the wizard again?

Comment: Are you trying to reinstall the OS? Or just update the settings from the 'startup wizard'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fresh installation of OS X will bring the 'wizard' back, but there is no real need to go to that extreme.

All of these initial settings can be changed at anytime.  This is done in the **System Preferences**.

Go to **** Menu > **System Preferences** or click its icon on the **Dock**

[image: System Pref Icon]

From here you can change Language settings, iCloud account (iTunes, Apple ID) and many other initial settings.

For example, to find the iCloud settings, you can type "iCloud" into the search bar and the appropriate settings will highlight.

[image: System Pref]

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to run the setup process again then remove the file `/var/db/.AppleSetupDone` and reboot. In Terminal : `sudo rm -f /var/db/.AppleSetupDone`

Your Mac will then go through the process once more.

Comment: Note that you should enter this command *very carefully*. Anytime you see `sudo rm`, a little alarm should go off in your head, saying "if I mess this up, I could destroy something important."